# Modifying value of superclass through subclass, and calling the value of the superclass in another subclass

Tags: java

I'm trying to modify a value in a superclass from a subclass, and call that value from another subclass. For some reason when I do the value becomes null, or resets. I was working on a larger scale project, but ran into this problem and figured it'd be easier for everyone if I tested it in a smaller program. Here's what I've got:

```
public class Superclass {
    
    private int x;
    
    protected void setX(int n) {
        this.x = n;
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }
    
    protected int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}


public class Subclass extends Superclass {  
    public void begin() {
        setX(55);   
        Subclass2 subclass2 = new Subclass2();
        subclass2.begin();
    }
}

public class Subclass2 extends Superclass {
    public void begin() {
        System.out.println(getX());
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
        subclass.begin();
    }
}
```

The superclass value successfully sets to 55, but when I call it from Subclass 2 it returns 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating a new object `subclass2` here

```java
public void begin() {
  setX(55);
  Subclass2 subclass2 = new Subclass2();
  subclass2.begin();
}
```

The `x` in `subclass2` is not the same as the `x` in `subclass`. And since `x` is not initialized in `Subclass2`, a primitive `int` by default has a value of 0.

The value of `x` is 0 when you instantiate either `Subclass` or `Subclass2`. The `x` in `subclass` became 55 because you called `begin()` on `subclass`, which `setX(55)`. During `begin()`, a totally different object `subclass2` was created. `subclass2`'s `x` is never touched. Therefore, calling `begin()` on `subclass2` prints 0.

Comment: But doesn't the X in the superclass stay the same, no matter what I instantiate?

Comment: No it doesn't stay the same. A value in a superclass is not a `static` value. It gets instantiated new every time you call its or one of its children's constructors.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you. How would I go about saving the Integer so I could call it then?

Comment: Are you asking how you can have a value on the class so it is shared by all instances of the class? If that's the case, what you want is a `static` variable. Like `private static int x;` There are plenty of resources to learn about those. Just Google something like "java static variable".